# Web2py how to set default form value list

Tags: python, web2py

I have in my db.py file

```
PROFILE_TYPE=["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"]

db.define_table('Item_Profile', 
                Field('uuid', 'string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), default=uuid.uuid4(), readable=False, writable=False),
                ...
                Field('documentType', 'string', requires=IS_IN_SET(PROFILE_TYPE), label="Select Profile for Document"),
                auth.signature)
```

I have an "edit page" where I'm referencing the model and I'm trying to set a default value but am having trouble. By this point, The value has already been set to one of the values in the list.

**document.py**

```
db.document_profile.documentType.default = db.document_profile.documentType
```

I figured this would take the value set from the list of choices and place it as the default value... I get nothing

Comment: What do you mean by, "By this point, The value has already been set to one of the values in the list"? The value of *what* has been set? Please show the relevant code. Note, `db.document_profile.documentType` is a DAL `Field` object -- it is not a value.

Comment: Well, if the record has already been filled I don't think it would be a good idea to set a new default value since you would be overwriting the old one, I'm guessing this because you said you have an "edit page". If you want to set a default value the you should be doing **Field('documentType', 'string', requires=IS_IN_SET(PROFILE_TYPE), default='some value from PROFILE_TYPE')**. If you REALLY need to set a new default value then you should do it in the controller, something like: **record=SQLFORM(db.Item_profile, request.args(0)) record.vars.documentType='A new default value'**. my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Try by passing the `zero` parameter to the validator. So the user can select one from the list and if they miss that step the form won't be accepted.

```
Field('documentType', 'string',
      requires=IS_IN_SET(PROFILE_TYPE, zero='Select one'),
      label="Select Profile for Document"),
```